# Asp.net Application throwing System.OutOfMemoryException in Windows server 2003

Tags: asp.net

I am using Neo load to test the performance of my ASP.NET 2.0 application. The application works fine until the memory of the w3wp.exe process reaches about 800000K and then it starts throwing System.OutOfMemoryException. The ASP.NET application is hosted in Windows server 2003 SP2 machine and the machine has 4GB of RAM. How can i get to know the reason for this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 800000K threshold is also mentioned (as 800MB) in the following article:

[Troubleshooting System.OutOfMemoryExceptions in ASP.NET](http://blogs.iis.net/webtopics/archive/2009/05/22/troubleshooting-system-outofmemoryexceptions-in-asp-net.aspx)

> When your worker process approaches 800MB in private bytes, your
>   chances of seeing an OOM condition begin to increase simply because
>   the chances of finding a large, contiguous piece of memory within the
>   2GB address space begin to decrease significantly.

The article then goes on to cover common scenarios that lead to this situation, such as the usage of large data sets, runaway session or application data storage, usage of debuggable assemblies, lots of exceptions thrown and even certain uses of regular expressions.

It ends with some pointers to resources to help troubleshooting Out of Memory exceptions, like the [Debug Diagnostic Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=24370) and information about garbage collection in .NET. But the most valuable resource may be this list of 21 blog posts from an ' escalation engineer' at Microsoft's ASP.NET developer support team:

[MSDN Blogs > If broken it is, fix it you should > The 21 most popular blog posts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/05/21/the-21-most-popular-blog-posts.aspx)